# Phrase for the belief that your field of study or project has higher merit

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a phrase for the act of rating one's activity greater then another person's activity.

An elementary school teacher might state that reading a chapter with your child is critical but an instructor at a gym might put a greater emphasis on social interaction and physical activity at that age takes precedents.  Both are vital for a well rounded child, but each individual rates their activity greater than the others.  What is that called?

Comment: What meaning are you trying to convey? Is it a fact or a judgment? Should the word have a negative or positive connotation, or just be neutral? Are you looking for a noun, verb, or adjective? Please provide an example sentence that would make the particular word more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

That is called *self-aggrandisement* or *self-importance* (or [*bumptiousness*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bumptiousness)).

> **Self-aggrandizement:** The action or process of promoting oneself as being powerful or important.
>
> Example: Critics accused him of self-aggrandizement. [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-aggrandizement)

Comment: Probably involved, though surely a Professor of Education might be _expected_ to judge on such issues, without getting accused of self-aggrandisement. And the term is far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is encapsulated in the term [bias](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/bias):

> bias - a partiality that prevents objective consideration of an issue or situation

In your example, you could get more specific with "professional bias."